# Overwriting an existing Heroku app

Tags: deployment, heroku, overwrite

I have a Sinatra app, hosted on Heroku. Lately, I've been developing that same app from a different folder. It's not a branch, it's just a parallel app / directory with identical contents but different code. I want to push this new app to Heroku, overwriting the app that's currently there. I don't want to merge the two locally, just continue from the new one while keeping the old. What's the proper command sequence for this? I have doubts about running `heroku create`, as that will result in a new app. Thanks!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Firstly this is certainly possible. The process is quite simple, firstly we need to add Heroku as a new remote repository to your new app.

```
heroku git:remote -a project
```

You would replace the 'project' with your Heroku app name. Secondly you would need to force a push to Heroku.

```
git push -f heroku master
```

Note: We are using an '-f' to force the push.

Comment: I'm in rails 4 - got this error: !`git:remote` is not a heroku command. !See `heroku help` for additional details.

Comment: @zero_cool you probably needed to update your heroku toolbelt