# How to push new github repository to existing heroku app

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Assume I have an existing heroku app called 'abc.herokuapp.com' here i want replace the entire code of this app means i want to push the new github repository to this existing heroku app. I want to delete the entire code from existing heroku and push new code from github.

Comment: You can find the answer for your question in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437903/overwriting-an-existing-heroku-app

Comment: hey thanks marcus. you saved my day. working superb.